# Install Yum/Dnf in a Virtualenv

Tags: package-management, yum, python3, dnf, virtualenv

I've created a Virtualenv (with python3.6) and want to install yum/dnf package in that environment. Is there any way to do that? As `import dnf` or `import yum` giving me error in that environment -> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'`, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yum'` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

well, that's kind of the point of a virtualenv: to separate it from the python packages of your system, in this case `dnf`. There's ways to break that when creating a virtualenv:

```
usage: venv [-h] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--clear] [--upgrade] [--without-pip] [--prompt PROMPT] [--upgrade-deps] ENV_DIR [ENV_DIR ...]

Creates virtual Python environments in one or more target directories.

positional arguments:
  ENV_DIR               A directory to create the environment in.

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --system-site-packages
                        Give the virtual environment access to the system site-packages dir.
```

So, use `--system-site-packages` when creating your virtual environment.

---

You might really want a separate installation of DNF. Understandably, being 100% a distro-specific tool, there's no working pypi package for it. So, manual installation would still work, as described in the dnf git repo README.

---

**Note**: that DNF will still use the DNF configuration in /etc/, the cache in /var, the libs in /lib and install to your system root. If you want to change that, you need to tell it to use different config files.

Comment: I just tried `python3.6 -m venv --system-site-packages .` but still not able to import.

Answer (score 0):

Yum and dnf are Linux package manager. In Virtualenv, you can install Python packages via pip (python package manager).